# How to disable window maximize effect in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, window, effects

In 13.04 when you maximize or snap a window to the screen's borders, instead of instantly changing its size, it does a little animation - it shrinks/expands to the appropriate size. How do I turn this off? I dug around in effect settings, but nothing there did anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Effects* → *All effects* tab → uncheck *Maximization*.

Comment: Where is the checkbox for effects?

Comment: no such menue in 'Kubuntu 20.04'