# How to Disable Automatic Maximize when Dragging a Window

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde

i have two monitions. fist is horizontal placed and second vertical placed .

First-Monitor: ▄▄ Second-Monitor: █

when i drag a window from on to the other monitor its always maximized. i don't want this.

Any idea where i could disable this?

i use:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 6.2.0-34-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
Memory: 31,3 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
```

I have tried:

```sh
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter auto-maximize false
No such schema “org.gnome.mutter”
```

and read and tried [How to disable window maximize effect in Kubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302559/how-to-disable-window-maximize-effect-in-kubuntu)

Any idea where i could disable this?

Answer (score 0):

for some reason (idk whey) it helps me to disable here the:

Desktop Effects - System Settings > Screen Edge (Highlights screen edge when approaching)

[image]

But it not works when:

Window in First-Monitor ▄▄ is maximized and i move it
to the lover halv of the Second-Monitor █
Then it jumps up and fills out all of the Second-Monitor again.

As Workaround i need to do:

1. un-maximze window in First-Monitor
2. move un-maximze window from First-Monitor to Second-Monitor (maybe near Bottom half)